# How to make JTextField semi-transparent

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, draw, jtextfield

I am trying to create a JTextField with semi-transparent background (i.e. black background with alpha value of `120`). My current code is:

```
    public static void designTextField(final JTextField tf) {
        tf.setBorder(null);
        tf.setFont(new Font("Comfortaa", Font.PLAIN, 30));

        tf.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 120));
        tf.setForeground(new Color(200, 200, 200, 200));
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to be working. Here are the pictures this code results in (there are two text fields):

**No text entered:**

[image: No text entered]

**Text entered:**

[image: Text entered]

As you see there're several weird drawing bugs, and both text fields seem to be fully non-transparent. How can I fix this?

Comment: Swing components usually don't work good with transparency. Take a look at https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/

Answer (score 0):

Swing perfectly works with transparency. You just need to add

```
tf.setOpaque(false);
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/problems.html
section "Problem: Visual artifacts appear in my GUI" explains.

Comment: I already tried this, and it results in the text fields simply getting completely white: https://sc.reflex.rip/PHcyfX.png

Comment: To have semi-transparent text field background you additionally need to override the way the component painted: `JTextField tf = new JTextField() {
                @Override
                protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                    g.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0, 100));
                    g.fillRect(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
                    super.paintComponent(g);
                }
            };`